# Getting too many matches for one string segment in regex (python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex script for finding all instances of money in a text, and my code works correctly but I can't figure out why it's finding multiple versions of things in my strings.

For example, in this code:

```
string = "$50.00"
print "number dollars: "
print re.findall("\-?\(?\$?\s*\-?\s*\(?(((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))?(\.\d{1,4})?)|((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))(\.\d{0,4})?))\)?\ ?(one)?\ ?(two)?\ ?(three)?\ ?(four)?\ ?(five)?\ ?(six)?\ ?(seven)?\ ?(eight)?\ ?(nine)?\ ?(ten)?\ ?(eleven)?\ ?(twelve)?\ ?(thirteen)?\ ?(fourteen)?\ ?(fifteen)?\ ?(sixteen)?\ ?(seventeen)?\ ?(eighteen)?\ ?(nineteen)?\ ?(hundred)?\ ?(thousand)?\ ?(million)?\ ?(billion)?\ ?(trillion)?\ ?(dollars)?\ ?(pounds)?\ ?(euros)?", string)
```

This is the result I get:

```
number dollars: 
[('50.00', '50.00', '50', '', '', '.00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')]
```

this is the regex by itself:

```
\-?\(?\$?\s*\-?\s*\(?(((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))?(\.\d{1,4})?)|((\d{1,3}((\,\d{3})*|\d*))(\.\d{0,4})?))\)?\ ?(one)?\ ?(two)?\ ?(three)?\ ?(four)?\ ?(five)?\ ?(six)?\ ?(seven)?\ ?(eight)?\ ?(nine)?\ ?(ten)?\ ?(eleven)?\ ?(twelve)?\ ?(thirteen)?\ ?(fourteen)?\ ?(fifteen)?\ ?(sixteen)?\ ?(seventeen)?\ ?(eighteen)?\ ?(nineteen)?\ ?(hundred)?\ ?(thousand)?\ ?(million)?\ ?(billion)?\ ?(trillion)?\ ?(dollars)?\ ?(pounds)?\ ?(euros)?
```

Comment: Turn all the capturing groups into non-capturing (add `?:` after `(` in grouping constructs)

Comment: All groups and patterns inside the expression are optional - you should think about matching at least 1 obligatory subpattern and build a new pattern around it. Have a look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/fPkjBH) - it will always matchs empty or all-whitespace strings.

Answer (score 0):

The results contain a string from each and every [parenthesized group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), corresponding to the portion of the string matched by the subexpression in each group, in order of opening parentheses (e.g. `(\d+(\.\d+)?)` would give `['50.00', '.00']`). To prevent the contents of a group from being captured, prefix the subexpression with a `?:` (e.g. `(?:,\d{3})*|\d*)`); this creates a [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap).

The majority of the groups are for words that don't appear in the string, which produces most of empty strings in the result.